# how addChild is being used in below AS3 code?

Tags: actionscript-3, addchild

For `addChild(iconObject)` (second line inside function `startAmoebaAttack()`), can anyone explain me where will `iconObject` be added in? because it doesn't have any object or array before `addChild` like `iconObject.addChild(newSoldier);`

```
    private var iconObject:Sprite;      

    public function startAmoebaAttack() {   
        iconObject = new Sprite();
        addChild(iconObject);
        createSoldierIcon();            
    }



    public function createSoldierIcon(){
        soldierIcon = new Array();
        for(var i:uint = 0; i<soldierLeft; i++){
            var newSoldier:SoldierIcon = new SoldierIcon();
            newSoldier.x = 65 + i *24;
            newSoldier.y = 590;                 
            iconObject.addChild(newSoldier);
            soldierIcon.push(newSoldier);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will automatically run it in [`this`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#this)'s context (same as `this.addChild(iconObject)`). In your  case `this` is descendant of [`DisplayObjectContainer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html) .

Comment: Thanks for the answer!